# Wordpress - 404 error instead of custom error page for non existing pdf

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, pdf, mod-rewrite

Custom "Page not found " is working on regular pages , if pages does not exist.

I test by manually typing wrong url  and it works.

But i have some pdf files . The url will end in ".pdf"  and if file does not exist it is giving a 404 error , not custom page .

Is there any different setting for pdf pages ?

i believe rewrite rule for page not found  is correct in .htaccess. I want to know what special about the PDF file . Did Anybody had this issue??

Comment: Can you provide a copy of your .htaccess? Sounds like the server is serving its 404 for static files. Does the same issue happen when you go to a nonexistent .png or .zip?

Comment: yes same happening with images

Comment: Okay, if you'll update your question with your .htaccess, I'll see if I can provide some help.